# How do I get all edge ids from a cluster

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I have a cluster of nodes, and when I select the cluster, I want to extract all the node ids and the edge ids. However, it seems to me that while `network.getNodesInCluster` retrieves all the nodes, there's no equivalent for edges. I've tried using `network.getBaseEdges` but it only returns the edge ids from the original edge connected to the cluster. It does not return edges between nodes that are in the cluster.

So, if I have a bunch of nodes in a cluster, and the nodes inside the cluster have edges connecting them together - how do I get a list of all the edges inside the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `network.getNodesInCluster`, loop them over and use `network.getConnectedEdges` to get all connected edges. Make sure to deduct duplicates.